# Rails JQuery UI Datepicker default hour

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a Rails app with the Jquery UI datepicker.  I can select the "Due" date fine but the Hour:Minutes:Seconds for the "Due" date becomes 00:00:00. I would like for this to default at 5:00:00 pm.  I'm not sure if it's easier to do from the Jquery side or the Rails side.  I'm relatively new to both so some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found 2 ways of doing this.

I can set the time format in jquery to include the time.

```
$('#rfq_due').datepicker(dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy <set time here e.g. 19:00:00>')
```

but it showed the time on the datepicker so instead i wen with the controller route

in my rfqs_controller

```
  def create
    @rfq = Rfq.new(rfq_params)
    @rfq.due.change({hour: 17})
    respond_to do |format|
...
```

Hope this helps someone